# No parameterless constructor with Model Binding in MVC with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I Have an Asp.Net MVC 4 Application and I'm using Simple Injector, I configured everything my application starts whell but when I try to post an exemplo form (when system will need the injection) is says "No constructor parametherless defined" to this object. It means that the injections is not working, but I think all is configured fine.

SimpleInjectorInitializer class:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SimpleInjectorInitializer), "Initialize")]
    public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

            InitializeContainer(container);
            container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            container.Verify();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
        }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        SimpleInjectorContainer.RegisterContainer(container);
    }
}
```

Container class (Where a register my dependencies)

```
public static class SimpleInjectorContainer
    {
        public static void RegisterContainer(Container container)
        {
            container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IPessoaRepository, PessoaRepository>();
        }

    }
```

I already have the assemblies:

SimpleInjector
SimpleInjector.Integration.Web
SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc

StackTrace

```
MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +114
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197

[MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto. Tipo de objeto 'Cerocha.Domain.Entities.Pessoa'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +531
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Stack trace my friend, stack trace. Post the stack trace please. Without such information, all we can do is guess, which will not really help you.

Comment: @user3670112, Show the controller that is giving the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to inject dependencies into your view model object. This is something that is not supported by MVC by default and not supported by the Simple Injector integration package, because it is a bad idea to mix runtime data with dependencies.

Your view models should not contain any behavior. Once you separate data and behavior, tou don't need to inject dependencies into view models and your problem will dissappear.